# How to install Flutter app on iPhone from windows PC

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, mobile

I'm currently developing with some friends a mobile app using Flutter. But we can't seem to find a working method to install the app on iPhone (none of us has a mac pc)

Any suggestions?

We even tried installing first macOs on a VM but nothing works.

Comment: You cannot install an iOS app never without a Mac. If you doesn't have a mac then make a fake of it on Windows. Google this: Hackintosh Zone

Comment: However, Hackintosh is a violation of your agreement with apple.  If you have a moral compass, steer clear.

Comment: Ehh, don't recommend Hackintosh Zone for anyone please. Nowadays if you want to install Hack on your machine you prepare OpenCore config and download macOS into USB pendrive using native mechanims that downloads files from Apple servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install an iOS app without a Mac. Consider using a macOS virtual machine on your Windows PC.

Then you can able to run ios apps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Buy a cheap Mac that suits your needs. I bought a used Mac mini 2014 for about 130 EUR. Keep in mind that older Mac generations won't be compatible with the latest MacOS (like mine). Therefore you can't install the the latest Xcode, which is needed if your Phone has the latest Ios. I managed to deploy my App on newer Devices than my Mac-> MacOs-> Xcode Version supports by copying device profiles for the "deployment target" from newer Xcode versions.
   Consider patching the Mac with "OpenCore Legacy Patcher" to get the latest MacOS to an older Mac.
2. Try running MacOS in a Virtual Machine. Search for "Hackintosh". I also tried this, but gave up after several hours. Maybe my AMD CPU is not compatible.

Comment: Hackintoshes works just fine on AMD CPU's, they just need to be patched in config.plist (for OpenCore boot). Tbh if you have laptop with AMD CPU it's the worst scenario since GPU acceleration won't work, the best situation is when you have desktop with Intel CPU + not neccesary, but with AMD GPU or Intel CPU laptop where you disable discrete graphic card if it's not booting.

Using VM for me is pain, since it's really slow without GPU acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on a desktop machine. AMD 5800X3D CPU + Nvidia RTX 3800 GPU. Can you give me a short hint how to patch?

Comment: You can't (for sure) use Nvidia RTX 3080. If you disable it somehow (via BIOS or ACPI patching method) you could use NootedRed for 5800X3D integrated GPU but also, I'm not sure if it will work anyway.